# java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation:

Tags: weblogic12c

I'm getting below error on Weblogic 12c. It is working fine in eclipse. I tried
`<prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>` but no luck. Pls help.

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: 
when resolving overridden method "com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFStreamMetadata.mergeTree(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/w3c/dom/Node;)V" 
the class loader (instance of weblogic/utils/classloaders/ChangeAwareClassLoader) of the current class, 
com/sun/media/imageioimpl/plugins/tiff/TIFFStreamMetadata, and its superclass loader (instance of <bootloader>), 
have different Class objects for the type org/w3c/dom/Node used in the signature

                at com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageReader.readHeader(Unknown Source)

                at com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageReader.locateImage(Unknown Source)

                at com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageReader.seekToImage(Unknown Source)
```